# add UINavigationController onto a UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller

I'm putting a NavigationController as a child VC on a ScrollView. Here's the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = YES;

  _scrollView = [UIScrollView newAutoLayoutView];
  _scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
  _scrollView.delaysContentTouches = NO;

  [self.view addSubview:_scrollView];
  [_scrollView autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdgesWithInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

  _contentView = [UIView newAutoLayoutView];

  UIView *yellowView = [UIView newAutoLayoutView];
  yellowView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
  [_contentView addSubview:yellowView];
  [yellowView autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeTop];
  [yellowView autoSetDimensionsToSize:CGSizeMake(kScreenWidth, kScreenHeight)];

  [_scrollView addSubview:_contentView];

  _settingsNavigationController = [UINavigationController new];

  [self addChildViewController:_settingsNavigationController];
  [_contentView addSubview:_settingsNavigationController.view];
  [_settingsNavigationController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

  [_settingsNavigationController.view autoSetDimensionsToSize:CGSizeMake(kScreenWidth, kScreenHeight)];
  [_settingsNavigationController.view autoPinEdge:ALEdgeTop toEdge:ALEdgeBottom ofView:yellowView];
  [_settingsNavigationController.view layoutSubviews];

  [_contentView autoPinEdge:ALEdgeBottom toEdge:ALEdgeBottom ofView:_settingsNavigationController.view];
  [_contentView autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdgesWithInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
  [_contentView autoPinEdge:ALEdgeLeading toEdge:ALEdgeLeading ofView:self.view];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];

  PCConfigViewController *configViewController = [PCConfigController new];
  configViewController.morning = YES;
  configClockViewController.delegate = self;
  [_settingsNavigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:configViewController] animated:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
```

I can scroll to the NavigationController and see its root view controller but it doesn't respond to touches, even though the NavigationController was added as a child view controller. Any ideas why, or how to make it responsive to touch?

Comment: Probably because the scrollView is taking the touches. Honestly, why don't you put the Navigation Controller instead a regular UIView, and then have the root controller use a scrollView, seems like that would make more sense

Comment: Let me rephrase: Probably because the scrollView is taking the touches. I think it would make more sense to put a navigation controller inside a regular UIView instead of a scrollView, then have your child VC use a scrollView. Also, remember to call [vc addChildViewController:childvc]

Comment: the scrollview controller is inside of a side panel navigation, which touches are working for, so the scrollview isn't swallowing all touches. the nav controller's view is already being added as a child controller as well. not sure what else it could be.

Comment: got something working by adding a container subview to the scrollview in viewDidLoad and in viewDidAppear, the nav controller is added to the container subview.